# train, test and validation data set configuration to compare a machine learing method and ARMA method

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, arima, model-selection, train-test-split

I want to compare performance a machine learning method and Autoreressive Moving Average-ARMA(p,q) for time series data.

I do such a configuration:

First I divide data into three part:

- Trainig data(First %60 of data)
- Validation data(%20 part of data)
- Test data(%20 part of data)

Then,
for machine learning procedure:

1. Evaulate models for different combinations of hyper parameters using **training data**.
2. Choose the best model using a criterion among all models from the first stage by using unseen  **validation data**.
3. Get the predicted results using the selected model from second stage, by a new unseen **test data**.

For ARMA method:

4. Get all combinations of models such that ARMA(1,0), ARMA(2,0),..ARMA(p,0), ARMA(2,0),....ARMA(p,q)
5. Choose the best model using a criterion among all models from the fourth stage by using unseen  **validation data**.
6. Get the predictied results using the selected model from fifth stage by a new unseen **test data**.

Finally, I compare predicted values obtained at the 3th and 6th stages, by using a criterion and choose which method is the best.

I wantto learn, is such a confiuration is true? Or should I change the the configuration.

Thanks a lot for any help and taking your time.